# i only want the checked items in the arraylist to be added

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

having trouble only adding the checkboxstatus's that are checked to the gridview.

Protected Sub atasks_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim tasknamelist As New List(Of Boolean)

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
    ' Selects the text from the TextBox

    Dim checkboxstatus As CheckBox = CType(row.FindControl("tasknamebox"), CheckBox)
    tasknamelist.Add(checkboxstatus.Checked)




Next
GridView2.DataSource = tasknamelist
GridView2.DataBind()
UpdatePanel2.Update()
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GridView1.Rows(0)` should just be `row` (as you declared it)

```
 tasknamelist = checkboxstatus.Checked
```

is wrong, you assign a bool to a list, try this:

```
Dim tasknamelist As New List(Of Boolean)
tasknamelist.Add(checkboxstatus.Checked)
```

Comment: can you look at what i have so far, ill ppost up top

Comment: Then unmark my answer, so I can look further and/or someone els can give a correct answer ;)